# Como mostrar uma div com scrollTop após determinados pixels?

Tags: jquery, rolamento

Tenho uma div (fixed) que aparece quando a página é rolada para baixo e volta a aparecer quando a página é rolada para cima.
Eu preciso que ela só desapareça (quando rolar para baixo) a partir de 45px do body. Ou seja, enquanto o usuário só rolar 44,9px ela não some e, partir disso, sim.

Aqui meu exemplo:

```js
var position = $(window).scrollTop(); 

// should start at 0

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
        console.log('scrollDown');
        $('.a').addClass('mostra');
    } else {
         console.log('scrollUp');
         $('.a').removeClass('mostra');
    }
    position = scroll;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;  
    background: orange;
}
.a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.mostra {
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseando-me no seu código, fiz assim e funcionou:

```js
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

// should start at 0

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
        console.log('scrollDown');
        if(position > 45) {
            $('.a').addClass('mostra');
        }
    } else {
         console.log('scrollUp');
         $('.a').removeClass('mostra');
    }
    position = scroll;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;  
    background: orange;
}
.a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.mostra {
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

É possível fazer o que você deseja apenas com css, porém, não funcionará em navegadores muito antigos <strike>(mas ninguém liga, o importante é rodar no chrome).</strike>

**Fica aqui a dica caso alguém precise:**

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;  
    background: orange;
}
.a {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    /*Position Sticky é quem faz a mágica*/
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.mostra {
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Aqui está a lista de navegadores compatíveis e incompatíveis: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Comment: Interessante, não conhecia...

Comment: mas não entendi como funciona muito bem. como/onde determinar o estilo que muda ao rolar?

Comment: Interessante. Também não conhecia. Mas não compete com a pergunta: "*Eu preciso que ela só desapareça (quando rolar para baixo) a partir de 45px do body. Ou seja, enquanto o usuário só rolar 44,9px ela não some e, partir disso, sim.*"... Dessa forma ela não "desaparece"...